# How can I order by likes?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to display items from a table and order them by number of likes. The likes are in another table, and that makes me confused. The first table `images` looks like this:

```
images

id   url
1    blablabla.jpg
2    hejhej.png
3    picture.jpg
```

And the second one, `likes`, looks like this:

```
likes

id   image
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    3
5    2
```

Now I want the images to be ordered by most likes. What do I write in the query to make it look like this?:

```
hejhej.png - 3 likes
blablabla.jpg - 1 like
picture.jpg - 1 like
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me with my problem.

Comment: order by `more likes` descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT url, COUNT(likes.id) as likes
FROM images, likes
WHERE likes.image = images.id
GROUP BY images.id
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

---

To get records from the last 24 hours only, add this to your query:

```sql
WHERE likes.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: If I add a new column in the likes table called "date". Would you happen to know how I can get images with most likes during the latest 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    url,
    COUNT(likes.id) Likes
FROM
    images,
    likes
WHERE
    likes.image = images.id
GROUP BY
    images.url
ORDER BY
    Likes DESC
```

You select `FROM` both tables, `grouped by` the image url and `ordered` by the amount of likes, in `descending` order.